# starting to develop for jack-audio

Tags: c++, jack

I'm quite new to developing on linux, so sorry for the dumb question.
I'm trying to develop something with jack, and when I try to install the development headers and libraries, I have the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-dev : Depends: libjack0 (= 2:0.124.2~20150719-1~kxstudio3) but it is not going to be installed
```

I guess this is due to the fact I update jack from kxstudio repositories, but probably the development ones are different. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `libjack0`.

See what dependencies are in conflict, if any.

Provide output from package manager if you can't figure out how to resolve.

If all else fails, you can try installing from source (in a non-system directory)

Comment: well it worked, but unfortunately it unistall other programs ( ardour, qjackctl etc etc ) Don't know if reinstalling will messy up again the development :)

Comment: If you reinstall it will either fail or uninstall `libjack`.  How you handle it depends on what you need the Linux install for.  If it's your main machine (life's work, etc.) you may want to go back to your original setup and try installing from source.  If it's a hobby or "throw-away" test machine, just leave it as is unless you have problems.  Read up on your package manager and read ServerFault or the appropriate Linux distribution sites to plan out where you go from here.  HTH...

Comment: I had the same problem, installing would remove some of my necessary packages. But I was able to build my jack application after installing `libjack-jackd2-dev`on Ubuntu 20.04